# Object oriented design principle Abstraction

Tags: oop, abstraction, object-oriented-analysis

While reading about abstraction, I came across the following statement

"Abstraction captures only those details about an object that are relevant to the current perspective"

For eg.
From the driver's perspective, Car class would be

```
  public class Car
  {
     void start();
     void applybrakes();
     void changegear();
     void stop();
   }
```

From the mechanic's perspective, Car class would be

```
  public class Car
  {
     void changeOil();
     void adjustBrakes();
   }
```

My question,
While designing a system, do we design for one user perspective(either driver or mechanic) or can
we design for multiple user perspective and further abstract out based on user type?

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your use case you might need to deign for multiple users. In your example, if your car will be used by both the mechanic and the driver, then you cannot just ignore one set of users. In that case, you can still abstract details by using Interfaces.

You could design your object like this:

```
interface IDrivable {
    void start();
    void applyBrakes();
    void changeGear();
    void stop();
}

interface IFixable {
    void changeOil();
    void adjustBrakes();
}

public class Car : IDrivable, IFixable {
    // implement all the methods here
}
```

Now, when a mechanic wants the car, you don't give him a `Car` object, instead give him an `IFixable` object. Similarly, the driver gets an `IDrivable` object. This keeps the relevant abstraction for both sets of users simultaneously.

```
class Driver {

    private IDrivable car;

    public Driver(IDrivable car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public driveCar() {
        this.car.start();
        this.car.accelerate();

        //this is invalid because a driver should not be able to do this
        this.car.changeOil();
    }
}
```

Similary, a mechanic won't have access to the methods in the interface `IDrivable`.

You can read more about [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) here. Even though this is the MSDN link and uses C#, all major languages support interfaces.

Comment: Beat me to it. Good starter for ten.

Comment: But When i will create do this : var driver = new Driver(new Car()) than changeoil and adjustBrakes will gets called because Car class is implementing both the interfaces(IDrivable,IFixable ) . Actually I am confused here so as to what dependency to pass when calling constructor of mechanic ?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow `changeOil()` and `adjustBrakes()` will not be callable by Driver because even though you are creating a `Car` object, the driver is getting an `IDrivable` object and will only be able to call methods defined in the `IDrivable` interface

Comment: @xbonez Oh yes sorry I understood.I have asked question following your design with some confusion if you have some time to check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56596666/confusion-regarding-having-inheritance-or-not-in-my-design

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be inferring too much from "perspective." I wouldn't take perspective here to mean a person or user so much as a vantage point. The idea of a view here is maybe not even a good metaphor. What we're really talking about here is division of responsibility between the smaller objects that we use to compose the larger objects.

The whole point of this idea is decoupling and modularity. You want objects that you can pull out and replace without changing everything around them. So you want your objects to be coherent, for their methods and variables to be closely related.

You might be able to get some mileage from the user metaphor in terms of the interface-client relationship between objects.